# Find and replace in xml file with Python

Tags: python, xml, csv

I am really new to Python.
I have a xml file with html inside and a csv file.

xml file example:

```
<example>
  <name id="{{2}}">{{1}}</name>
  <class>{{3}}</class>
    <modules>
      <module>{{4}}</module>
      <module>{{5}}</module>
      <module>{{6}}</module>
    </modules>
</example>
```

CSV file with two columns:

```
1;Alex
2;345
3;10
4;math
5;pysics
6;chemistry
```

I have to replace values inside {{}} (references are in csv file in first column) with the values in second column of csv file.

I am able to read csv file successfully (No problem with that).
I am looking for solution to find and replace in xml file against each {{}}.

I tried

```
  i=1
  for line in inputfile.readlines():
     outputfile.write(line.replace('{{'+str(i)+'}}', 'value from 2nd colum of csv file'))
     i = i +1
```

but it is not replacing all the values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
from csv import reader

with open('test.xml') as inputfile:
    xml = inputfile.read()

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    for row in reader(csvfile, delimiter=';'):
        xml = xml.replace('{{%s}}' % row[0], row[1])

with open('output.xml', 'w') as outputfile:
    outputfile.write(xml)
```

This code uses the `csv` module, which means you don't have to deal with the complexity of handling escaping or quoting that might appear in your csv data.

Comment: Thanks for understanding my wrong html code and answer it. Just now i edited my code. I accept your answer.